# Tracking known Lead/Contact in Pardot

Tags: pardot

Using the Pardot tracking code we're able to track the behavior of unknown leads/contacts (using a prospect ID). The page that they land on will be sent via an email in which we can attach a Lead or Contact ID.

Is there a way Pardot can use that so when it syncs the prospects it updated the existing record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you could add a URL parameter to the link in the email. try adding: `?pi_list_email=<prospect_email_here>` to the end of the email (keeping in mind, if you already have parameters you will want to change the question mark [?] to an ampersand [&]).

Check out this resource for more details:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000315015&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1